# Can't read from serial0 using PySerial when python script starts at boot

Tags: python, boot, serial, uart

I have a Python script that uses Pyserial, connects to '/dev/serial0' and reads from it in loop.

The script works fine when starting it manually after the RPi is up. 
However, when I added the script's activation to crontab -e, it no longer works. I get many many `device disconnected or multiple access on port` errors.

I don't put the code here since it's not a code issue as it works fine when activated manually.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I got this one solved! Please see the great answer in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90013/uart-rx-stops-reading-data-after-working-correctly

Comment: If you found a solution then please make an answer to finish the question.